# How much do you think these Lego pieces are worth?

Tags: shopping, lego-group, value

I've got some very old LEGO brick from the 50s, and am wondering how much they are worth. I'd like an estimate because I know that they are now collectors items that might be worth something.

Here are some of the items:

- Three Lego Beetles that are in plastic very good condition in red black and grey
- A plastic red fire truck and a tanker that is red with written "Esso" on it and other small size Lego plastic trucks
- The Lego set 810 with all the items inside
- Another big wooden box of Lego
- Box number 750 containing some architectural buildings

Instructions are included with each box.

Comment: There's a site called brickpicker.com that could be used as a rough guide for what sets are worth. Like Gev said - you really have to find the right buyer though.

Comment: There's a guy named Michael Todd, goes by Bruno, who lives outside of San Diego. He's built up one of the largest private collections of Lego memorabilia, if you will, in the world. He has purchased plenty of stuff from the 50s and 60s over the years, and he'd be a great resource to reach out to with a question like this. He has recently opened a museum in conjunction with the San Diego Toy and Doll Museum in Poway, CA. You can contact him through his website: [http://www.lgauge.org/contact-us/](http://www.lgauge.org/contact-us/)

Comment: Your numbered sets might not be worth much. Your other sets would be best ID'd with a picture. Also, LEGO has never made Beatles products. Those have been made by off-brands and private sellers that make customized products. Your wooden blocks are also not LEGO bricks either, and thus probably have little value outside of standard wooden block value.

Answer (score 4):

My answer to this kind of question is always "it's worth exactly as much as someone is willing to give you for it."

That said, one could look up prices on BrickLink (assuming there are any for sale there) and go from there. Failing that, put them on eBay with a reserve/starting bid of whatever minimum amount would make it ok for you to part with them.

Comment: Apart from looking prices up on BrickLink, putting them online for sale requires an intent to sell